# Graph on the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$

Tags: set-theory, graph-theory

Let $V$ be the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. Let two distinct functions $f,g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ form an edge if and only if they differ in exactly one input $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $G=(V,E)$. Clearly, $G$ has cliques of cardinality $\aleph_0$. Is $\chi(G) = \aleph_0$?

Comment: This graph is Borel, and it would be interesting to ask whether there can be a Borel $\mathbb{N}$-coloring. If your edge relation connected points that differed finitely, then I believe there can be no Borel coloring, since it would give rise to a Borel selector on $E_0$, which is impossible. (For example, there can be no Borel coloring of the type that Chris describes.) But your relation is finer than $E_0$ and so a coloring needn't color the entire $E_0$ equivalence class differently.

Comment: Joel, I think this question is worthwhile to put it as a MO question!

Comment: Please go ahead!

Comment: It may be just me, but your non-reflexive unordered graph would be much easier to grasp if it were defined as: vertices functions N->N, and there is an edge between f and g if they differ for exactly one input. Of course, you may be trying to emphasise the logical form of the set of edges in the language of some fragment of set theory...

Comment: Good point, have modified the post accordingly.

Comment: If you replace the target set $\mathbf{N}$ with a 2-element set, the components of the resulting graph are all isomorphic and called "hypercubes". When the target set is $\mathbf{N}$ or $\mathbf{Z}$, it is also natural to put an edge only when $f-g$ is $\pm$ the Dirac function at some point, so that the resulting distance is the $\ell^1$-distance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, $\chi(G) = \aleph_0$. To see this, define $f \sim g$ if $\{n : f(n) \not= g(n) \}$ is finite. $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, all equivalence classes of $\sim$ are countable, and $\{f,g\} \in E \Rightarrow f \sim g$. (In fact, the equivalence classes of $\sim$ are precisely the connected components of $G$.) Thus, we can color $G$ with countably many colors simply by ensuring that, if $f$ and $g$ are in the same equivalence class, they are given different colors.